# Java Script recursivly adding a child ends in infinite loop

Tags: javascript

This is my function for adding a child. With flag it will only add child once. Without a flag it goes into infinite loop. Flag is global.

```
function addChildToParent(node, parent, child) {
    if (node.name == parent) {
        node.add(child);
        flag = true;
    }
    else if (flag==false){
        for (i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            addChildToParent(node.getChild(i), parent, type, child);
        }
    }
}
```

It is being called here, length of smth is 3.

```
request.onload = function () {
        var ecs=[];
        for(i=0;i<smth.length;i++){
            ecs[i]= new Node(smth[i],EC);
            flag=false;
            addChildToParent(node,smth[i],ecs[i]);
        }          
};
```

Function above is being called 2 times. 
Question is what am I doing wrong.

Comment: `flag` is global because you're defining it without var. When you set it to `true` it is then always `true`. Should probably give it a more descriptive name. And use `===` over `==` to avoid confusion down the line.

Comment: `i ` in for loops are global no var either, don't know the rest of code, but it can be overwritten if you have for loops elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks zer00ne, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to zer00ne comment of my post I have indentified the problem.
Variable `i` in `for` must be used with `var i`, or it gets overwritten somehow because its not local, but global variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            addChildToParent(node.getChild(i), parent, type, child);
        }
```

Fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should either replace `else if`  with `else` or add another condition to your `else if` condition like below

```
function addChildToParent(node, parent, child) {
    if (node.name == parent && flag !==false) {
        node.add(child);
        flag = true;
    }
    else if (node.name !== parent && flag == false){
        for (i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            addChildToParent(node.getChild(i), parent, type, child);
        }
    }
}
```